# Not able to access data pipeline from AWS lambds using SDK

Tags: amazon-data-pipeline

I have created aws lambda which will activate the data pipeline which will copy data from S3 to RDS. But i am not able to access data pipeline from aws lambda.

```
  public async Task<string> FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        context.Logger.LogLine("Creating client");
        AmazonDataPipelineClient dataPipelineClient = new AmazonDataPipelineClient();
        context.Logger.LogLine("client created successfully.");
        var listPipeLineRequest = new ListPipelinesRequest();
        listPipeLineRequest.Marker = string.Empty;
        ListPipelinesResponse response = await dataPipelineClient.ListPipelinesAsync(listPipeLineRequest);
        context.Logger.LogLine("response : " + response);
        context.Logger.LogLine("result " + response.PipelineIdList.Count.ToString());
        return input?.ToUpper();
    }
```

I am expecting the list of data pipeline that i have created. But its giving timeout exception. I am able to see logs till i call dataPipelineClient.ListPipelinesAsync only.